# Angular newbie : $scope variable need to be used twice to refresh a textarea

Tags: angularjs

I try AngularJS for the first time and I'm stuck on a problem.

In the debugger I see that the scope variable '$scope.xml' is correctly updated, but the display needs a second pass (second click) to refresh.

Here is a Plunker to see my problem : http://plnkr.co/edit/9PJsGeDqwjC6nmZHcEJV

I'm looking in the documentation but I can not find track to understand what I did not do well

Thank's a lot for your help !

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="testAngularJS">
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="testXML">
<div>XML<br/><textarea cols="60" rows="15" ng-model="xml" name="xml">{{xml}}</textarea></div>

<div><button ng-click="listTypDoc()">List !</button><br/>

<br/><button ng-click="clearXML()">Clear</button></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var app = angular.module('testAngularJS', []);

 app.controller('testXML', function($scope){

  $scope.url = 'listeTypDoc.txt';

    $scope.listTypDoc = function() {

        $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url: $scope.url,
                xhrFields: {
                   withCredentials: false
                },
                crossDomain: false
            }).done(function ( data ) {
               $scope.xml = data;
               debugger;
          });

        };

        $scope.clearXML = function() {
        $scope.xml = ''; 
        };

    })  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want to learn Angular you're better off without jquery. You should have a look at the $http service, and scope.$apply - this should help you in the right direction

Comment: I try to promote Angular at my office, because Angular seems to be simple. But we use a technology that talk only in XML and don't know JSon. $http service is difficult with XML (it use a tranformation, we don't like). But this is 'off topic' no ? Try the Plunker if you have 2 mn. Why do I need to click twice on the button List ? Thank's a lot if you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using a request outside the angularjs, you need to call $apply() after setting the data to the $scope.xml. Take a look in the apply method:

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope)

But it's better to use the services angularjs provides instead of using jquery.

Comment: It work's fine ! 
      $scope.xml = data;
      $scope.$apply();